# How to use dependencyManagement in a Multi-module project correctly？It always cannot work in my demo

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I create a simple multi-module maven demo to learning `dependencyManagement`, but the dependency cannot be found. How to use it correctly? (help me fix this demo or better give me an example. I have been confused for several days)

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- `TestQ11/pom.xml` ( parent module )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>localhost</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestQ11</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>app</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

- `TestQ11/app/pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TestQ11</artifactId>
        <groupId>localhost</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Your construction should work (although it is not necessary to repeat the version number in the dependency). It is probably just the IDE that is out of sync. Try to build your project (`mvn clean package`) and report errors (if any).

Comment: `mvn clean package` can package successfully, but why the IDEA give error message, and I cannot write code. Could you please give me a demo just like that?

Comment: So your Maven files are correct, you probably need to make an update in IntelliJ.